# Bootstrap 3 in IE7 and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to make bootstrap 3 compatible with IE7 and IE8.

I did insert this two script:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

but still can't work. Other than these, what else I need to do to fix this problem.

Comment: If your css is located on the same domain and called with a relative path, this will work. If you are using another domain to host your CSS, you will need to make a cross-domain proxy

Comment: Easy. Don't support IE7 or IE8

Comment: IE8 is well supported!! @IanBrindley

Comment: @StevenWeb Better still, don't support IE.

Comment: @IanBrindley got it you are right!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with bootstrap with IE7 and IE8; If you have used the grid system then you have to write separate style sheets for IE7 for the grids .You can have a look at how I tried to do it here  https://github.com/nanjekyejoannah/DelarkaSite .

Answer (score 1):

The CDN's are causing cross browser problems!!

You must deliver the `respond.js` and the `html5shiv` from your domain!!

I had the same problem and i took hours to find the solution!

**BTW: Bootstrap 3 is NOT supported in IE7 !!!** but for IE8 it is absolutely ok!!